# crear textarea responsive

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando un formulario  responsive y todos los input type except el textarea no me lee el siguiente código css dentro de head:

```css
input[type=textarea]
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Y este es el código del textarea del formulario

```html
<textarea rows="20" name="message" cols="40" maxlength="1300" required></textarea>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer la llamada desde el css para que el textarea se visualice de forma responsive?
Gracias

Comment: Estás definiendo el css como `input[type=textarea]` pero un textarea no es un tag `<input>`, si no `<textarea>`... por qué en vez de eso no pruebas a ponerle ese css directamente al `textarea {width: 100%;....}`?

Comment: Funcionando perfectamente. Gracias Benito.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner una clase al textarea y por medio de esa clase poner el estilo o usar el selector del textarea.

```css
textarea{
    background-color: teal;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* O con una clase */
.textarea{
    background-color: teal;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="40" class="textarea" maxlength="1300" required></textarea>
```

PD: Le puse solo 5 filas y color de fondo para que se vea el resultado.

Comment: No hace falta la clase, si quiere que todos sean iguales (su selector está hecho para aplicarse a todos los input de type textarea si te fijas, aunque eso no existe :)). Con quitar el punto de la clase en tu css y dejar el selector ya llegaría, y es exactamente lo que busca la pregunta.

Comment: No es recomendable hacer eso... puede generar confusiones... es como poner una clase llamada `div` a una etiqueta `div`, `texarea` , `input`, etc... Lo correcto sería: 1) Si se desea aplicar el estilo a todos los `texarea`, se debe usar a la etiqueta `texarea` como selector en el CSS; o 2) Si se desea aplicar el estilo a ese `texarea` en específico, tu ejemplo estaría bien, pero vendría mejor ponerle una clase con otro nombre diferente a la etiqueta...

Comment: @Benito-B buen punto. @Cris22 es obvio que es un ejemplo, el OP le puede poner el nombre que quiera a la clase. Creo que todos lo han entendido y la verdad no hace falta ni explicarlo. Es como ponerle `<title>Titulo</title>` en serio crees que se debe explicar eso?? Pues por ahí va ese nombre de clase que le puse.

Answer (score 0):

Un Elemento HTML se compone por su `tag` y por `atributos`

```html
<tag atributo1="valor_atributo1" atributo2="valor_atributo2" ..etc>
```

En CSS los selectores más habituales

- #id -> un `#` de prefijo
- .clase -> un `.` de prefijo
- tag -> Sin prefijo

Además, los [[ ]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) en un selector indican que deben buscar atributo

```css
algun_selector[attributo_nombre=atributo_valor]
```

Donde `algun_selector` puede ser `#id`, `.clase`, `tag` o alguno otro o combinaciones de otros.

Entonces tu selector:

```css
input[type=textarea] { }
```

Busca un elemento con la siguiente estructura:

```
<input type="textarea" >
```

Lo cual evidentemente no es lo que tu quieres, simplemente debes colocar el tag

```
textarea
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```